# How to get the response and return result from controller action to view

Tags: php, ajax, yii

i have written this script in View. In onblur event i have check whether the mail id is already exits r not.for that i have to pass mailId id to the controller action and i want to get the return result.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("Approval/checkMailid"); ?>",
        data: mailId,
        success: function() {
          return data;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Return 1 or 0 from the controller and use `if` condition inside `success` to handle that response

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionCheckMailid($mailId)
{
   $model = YourModel::model()->findAll('id = :mid', array(':mid'=>$mailId));

   echo json_encdoe($model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to throw a 404 page and ajax error handle can catch it.

```
public function actionCheckMailid($mailId){
    $exist = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select count(*) from your_email_table where id_email = :id_email')
                        ->queryScalar(array(
                            'id_email' => $mailId
                        ));
    if($exist > 0){
        echo json_encode(array(
            'success'=>true
        ));
    }else{
        throw new CHttpException('Email can not be found');         
    }                           
}
```